# Undefined contract address when using useDapp's useCall hook

Tags: reactjs, ethereum

Docs referenced: https://usedapp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide.html#custom-hooks

Version of usedapp in package.json: "@usedapp/core": "^0.11.0"

Im using the useCall hook to call one of my functions that returns an integer that shows total supply. Here is the my custom hook:

```
import { useCall } from "@usedapp/core"
import { Contract } from '@ethersproject/contracts'

const useTotalSupply = (contractAddress, ethInterface) => {
   const ethContract = new Contract(contractAddress, ethInterface)
   console.log("Found address for contract object: " + ethContract.address)
   const { value, error } = useCall(
       ethContract,
       'getTotalCurrentSupply',
       []) ?? {}
   if (error) {
       console.error(error.message)
       return -1 
   }
   return value?.[0] 
}

export default useTotalSupply
```

This is how I'm using the hook in my component

```
const MintCounter = () => {

   const totalSupply = useTotalSupply(ethContractAddress, ethInterface)
   return (
       <Box>
           <Stat>
               <StatLabel>Total Mints</StatLabel>
               <StatNumber>{totalSupply}</StatNumber>
           </Stat>
       </Box>
   )
}
```

After building my app, I'm seeing the following error:
[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRFJ4.png)

I'm a bit confused by this error since I'm passing in the contract instance and I can see that the contract.address value has been set and I am seeing the address string on the console output. Is there something that I am missing in using this hook? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I was able to show the supply replacing `useCall` part:

```
    const {value: message} = useCall({
    contract: ethContract,
    method: "totalSupply",
    args: []
    }) ?? {}

   return String(message)
```

environment: ERC721 contract, local hardhat node (31337), usedapp 0.12